# Does a pronoun usually refer to the nearest preceding person(s)?

Tags: pronouns, they

See the following paragraph:

Then Judah said to his brothers, “What profit is it if we kill our brother and conceal his blood? Come, let us sell him to the Ishmaelites, and let not our hand be upon him, for he is our brother, our own flesh.” And his brothers listened to him. Then Midianite traders passed by. And **they** drew Joseph up and lifted him out of the pit, and sold him to the Ishmaelites for twenty shekels of silver. They took Joseph to Egypt.

Here I am asking about the pronoun "they" in the sentences *Then Midianite traders passed by. And **they** drew Joseph up and lifted him out of the pit, and sold him to the Ishmaelites for twenty shekels of silver.
*

Does "they" refer to "some Midianite traders" as those are the nearest preceding persons?

Comment: In this unusual case, *they* refers back to his brothers and not the Midianites. Read it this way: Judah's brothers listened to him... And they drew Joseph up... and sold him. Another switch: your translation has "they **drew Joseph up** and lifted him out of the pit," but the original has "they **(drew up and lifted) Joseph** out of the pit." Then, scholar Rashi has a tradition that there were multiple middlemen (they sold him to the Ishmaelites, and the Ishmaelites to the Midianites, and the Midianites into Egypt.)

Comment: The [online Encyclopedia Brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Midianites) says that the Midianites have traditionally been identified as Ishmaelites even though they were descended from Midian rather than Ishmael at least partly because of this passage in Genesis. I suspect that _Ishmaelite_ might have once meant "those who are not us but are closely related to us" to the Jewish people regardless of whether they were supposedly descended from Ishmael or not.

Comment: *They* refers to *Midianites*, [maybe](https://www.jfedgmw.org/jewish-life/vayeshev-the-sale-of-joseph).

Comment: This translation does break the usual rule. NASB, probably the most literal translation, best reflects the original Hebrew. Other versions amend/correct the phrasing (NKJV for instance amends to 'so the brothers pulled Joseph up' to conform with standard practice). There is always a trade-off in translation between word-for-word accuracy and making sense in a target language with different grammar (and polysemy).

Comment: Then Judah said to his brothers, “... and let not our hand be upon him," On a literal translation, I undrestand that Judah and his brothers literally did not want to touch Joseph as this would increase their guilt. One assumes that the Midianites were seen from a distance, and when Judah and his brothers could speak to them, they explained that there was a potential slave in the pit, and did they (The Midianites) want to buy him? Money changed hands, Judah and his brothers left, and the Midianites got their purchase, Joseph, out of the pit.